# search in toolbar vs actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-search

**Update:**

I am updating this post to make it easier to follow. I just updated my app to use Toolbar vs action bar. I have an activity MainDrawer2 which holds all the fragments loaded from the nav drawer. At the top I have a toolbar that I inflate with this menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">




    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        android:title="Search"/>



    <item android:id="@+id/action_barcode"
        android:icon="@drawable/bar"
        android:title="barcode"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:onClick="scanBarcode"/>



</menu>
```

On the above menu, the search icon is just a normal button with an onClick. When the onCLick is pressed it loads the Search.java:

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;
    private Menu optionsMenu;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        //getActivity().setTitle("Search");


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        return v;


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        this.optionsMenu = menu; // HERE

        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_searchHome);

        //searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query
        //make json variables to fill

        if (optionsMenu != null) {
            //(optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2)).collapseActionView();
        }


        // url to make request
        String url = "myURL";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;


        //todo: get json
        ReadJSONResult task = new ReadJSONResult(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b, String brewery){
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.postInvalidate();
        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        //adds beer data to shared prefs for beer tabs
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString("beerID",b);
        editor.putString("breweryID",brewery);
        editor.commit();
        Fragment_one = new BeerTabs();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }





}
```

The search.java then inflates a different menue that has the expandable search, which the onCLick gets applied too:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_searchHome"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

        android:title="Seach Beer"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_statisticsHome"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:onClick="goToStatistics"
        android:title="Your Statistics"/>

</menu>
```

Right now when I try an open up the searchBar with the new inflated menu I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.Search.onCreateOptionsMenu(Search.java:72)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1868)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1989)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:276)
       at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
       at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
       at android.support.v7.widget.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
       at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:459)
       at android.support.v7.internal.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:69)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Line 72 is:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. change in your menu.xml `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction` and add `app:actionViewClass`, example:

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@id/search_action"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_32_white_search"
       android:title="@string/search_action_title"
       app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
       app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
       />
   ```
2. set your toolbar as action bar (in `onCreate()`, for example) with [`setSupportActionBar()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar));
3. change your `onCreateOptionsMenu` code from

   ```
   searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
   ```

   to

   ```
   final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2);
   searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
   ```

Comment: so is searchView the submitted query? I am confused on how to retrieve the string the user types in

Comment: You will get your query in `onQueryTextSubmit()`: your code doesn't need any other serious changes except that I described above. Did you test app with toolbar on the device?

Comment: I just updated my entire question and code so you can see better what I am trying to accomplish/whats broken

Comment: As the answer points out. Change `app:showAsAction="never"` to `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Comment: And also (with Simon fix) inflate your menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` - check [Creating an Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) part of official menus guide.